# Additional printer settings button is unresponsive

Tags: 18.04, printing

In Settings > Devices > Printers I have two buttons 'Add a Printer' and 'Additional Printer Settings'. The latter is unresponsive when I click on it. I am using Ubuntu 18.04. What is the problem?

Comment: Is `CUPS` happy? `service cups status`, and `service cups-browsed status` will inform. It may be easier to find the Remote printer through CUPS `http://localhost:631` -> `Administration` -> `Find New Printers`.

Comment: CUPS is active. There are some errors/warnings about ecryptfs.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install Print Settings (system-config-printer).